# Effective way to create transposing table from three objects

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, transpose

I have three objects:

**Users**

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'User'
    },
    {
        id:2,
        name: 'User2'
    }
]
```

**Pages**

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Page'
    },
    {
        id:2,
        name: 'Page2'
    }
]
```

**Rights**

```
[
    {
        user_id: 1,
        page_id: 1,
        access: 'rw'
    },
    {
        user_id: 1,
        page_id: 2,
        access: 'ro'
    },
    {
        user_id: 2,
        page_id: 1,
        access: 'rw'
    },
]
```

What I need to do is display single table combining the data BUT the table has to be able to transpose AND I need to be able to edit values of each cell (rights) and the change should be reflected everywhere.

Here is current prototype so you see how it should look like:

[image][image]

At the moment I create two separate objects with data that fill each table and then simply show/hide the tables (transposing). This is rather complicated and not easy to wok with since I need to be able to edit values in cells and need the change to reflect in transposing.

I will appreciate any suggestion how to make this better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem. Give this a go:

Html:

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="mainController">
    <button ng-click="transposeTable()">Transpose</button>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Filter users</td>
                <td ng-repeat="col in (usersFirst ? users : pages)">{{col.name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in (usersFirst ? pages : users)">
                <td>{{row.name}}</td>
                <td ng-repeat="col in (usersFirst ? users : pages)">{{usersFirst ? getRight(col, row) : getRight(row, col)}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var appModule = angular.module('app', []);

appModule.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

$scope.users = [{ id: 1, name: 'User1' }, { id:2, name: 'User2' }];
$scope.pages = [{ id: 1, name: 'Page1' }, { id:2, name: 'Page2' }];
$scope.rights = [{ user_id: 1, page_id: 1, access: 'rw' }, 
    { user_id: 1, page_id: 2, access: 'ro' }, 
    { user_id: 2, page_id: 1, access: 'rw' }, 
    { user_id: 2, page_id: 2, access: 'no' }];

$scope.usersFirst = true;
$scope.transposeTable = function() {
    $scope.usersFirst = !$scope.usersFirst;
};
$scope.getRight = function(user, page) {
    return _.find($scope.rights, function(right) {
        return right.user_id === user.id && right.page_id === page.id;
    }).access;
};

});
```

Working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/kyp7nvng/5/

Comment: Very interesting solution! (I dont get the downvote on the question...) Now the only problem is the performance, the whole app gets really slow because of evaluating getRight() all the time. Also the background color of the cell is determined by the return of this function, so to make it work I would have to do it twice... Any ideas how to work around it?